# Append-only access to Azure Cosmos DB/Container

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, rbac

Is it possible to set up append (add) only access to a (selected) container in Azure CosmosDB?
Or (as plan B) - at a higher (database) level?

What are known good approaches to support immutability of  events in Event Sourcing system implemented with Azure CosmosDB?

Comment: Cosmos DB doesn't really have append-only modes for its containers. Have you considered managing permissions and access? Maybe through a Cosmos DB user that has read-only permissions, and keeping your writes separate?

Comment: Not all writes will do. I want to exclude update and delete perms when accessing container/database.

Comment: I don't understand your reply: user permissions may be "all" or "read-only", and setting up a read-only user would prevent updates and deletes. You could then use such a configured user for all of your access aside from writing (and carefully guard your write-enabled operations, within your app). This has to be managed within your application, however you decide to achieve it.

Comment: In general user permissions on a given resource are create, read, update, delete. In Azure, it seems like OOB roles for Cosmos DB only compose either read (Reader role) or CRUD (Contributor role). So I wonder if one could compose _custom_ role for the Cosmos DB (or granularly, per container) with CR-only permission. Or what are alternative solutions.